# Accessing data in chunks using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, large-data

I have a large text file, separated by semi-column. I am trying to retrieve the values of a column (e.g. the second column) and work on it iteratively using numpy. An example of data contained in a text file is given below:

```
10862;2;1;1;0;0;0;3571;0;
10868;2;1;1;1;0;0;3571;0;
10875;2;1;1;1;0;0;3571;0;
10883;2;1;1;1;0;0;3571;0;
...
11565;2;1;1;1;0;0;3571;0;
11572;2;1;1;1;0;0;3571;0;
11579;2;1;1;1;0;0;3571;0;
11598;2;1;1;1;0;0;3571;0;
11606;2;1;1;
```

Please note that the last line may not contain the same number of values as the previous ones.

I am trying to use pandas.read_csv to read this large file by chunks. For the purpose of the example, let's assume that the chunk size is 40.

I have tried so far 2 different approaches:

1) 
Set `nrows`, and iteratively increase the `skiprows` so as to read the entire file by chunk.

```
nrows_set = 40
n_it = 0
while(1):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, nrows=nrows_set , sep=';',skiprows = n_it * nrows_set)
    vect2 = df[1] # trying to access the values of the second column -- works
    n_it = n_it+1
```

**Issue when accessing the end of the file:** Pandas generates an error when ones tries to read a number of rows bigger than the number of rows contained in the file.
For example, if the file contains 20 lines, and `nrows` is set as 40, the file cannot be read. My first approach hence generated a bug when I was trying to read the last 40 lines of my file, when less than 40 lines were remaining.

I do not know how to check for the end of file before trying to read from the file - and I do not want to load the entire file to obtain the total rows number since the file is large. Hence, I tried a second approach.

2)
Set `chunksize`. This works well, however I have an **issue when I then try to acess the data in chunk**:

```
reader = pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=40, sep=';')
for chunk in reader :
   print(chunk) # displays data -- the data looks correct
   chunk[1]     # trying to access the values of the second column -- generates an error
```

What is the data type of `chunk`, and how can I convert it so as this operation works?

Alternatively, how can I retrieve the number of lines contained in a file without loading the entire file in memory (solution 1))?

Thank you for your help! 
Gaelle

Answer (score 0):

chunk is a data frame.

so you can access it using indexers (accesors) like `.ix / .loc / .iloc / .at / etc.`:

```
chunk.ix[:, 'col_name']
chunk.iloc[:, 1]  # second column
```

Comment: Great! I just tried and it works perfectly. Thank you so for your rapid answer.
Gaelle

Comment: Sorry, I spoke too soon, I have the same error as before.

    np.diff(chunk.iloc[:,1])  # generates an error

I guess I have to use something like pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix

Comment: @Gaelle, you can use similar pandas method: `chunk.ix[condition, 'col_name'].diff()`